# how do you fetch gmail user's email address using gmail java api?

Tags: java, gmail-api

From [Google's official doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages), here is how you can create email messages with their java api:

```
  public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject,
      String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                       new InternetAddress(to));
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setText(bodyText);
    return email;
  }

/**
   * Create a Message from an email
   *
   * @param email Email to be set to raw of message
   * @return Message containing base64url encoded email.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws MessagingException
   */
  public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
      throws MessagingException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(bytes);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
    return message;
  }
```

So you need a `from` field, which leads to the questions: how do you fetch the user's email address?

Comment: Which user?  Fetch it from what?

Comment: The user, on behalf of whom the app is handling the mails.

Comment: From some google database, I suppose?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile#try-it) to get the email address of the user:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile?fields=emailAddress&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "emailAddress": "foo@example.com"
}
```

In Java this could look like:

```
GetProfile profile = service.users().getProfile("me").execute();
System.out.println(profile.getEmailAddress());
```